# Как печатать текст в поток входных данных?

Tags: c++, bash

У меня есть программа на c++, она задают запросы и на них надо отвечать. Как отвечать на запросы из bash скрипта? Программа считывает из stdin и выводит в stdout. Суть вопроса в том чтобы программа увидела запросы и как это сделать. Ответы зависят от вопросов, и отвечать на них нужно сразу. То как генерировать ответы я знаю. Вопрос в том как дать их программе.

Comment: А последовательность ответов всегда одинаковая, или зависит от поведения программы? Если одинаковая, то просто запустить ее так: `./программа <файл_с_ответами.txt`

Comment: Ответы всегда разные

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите. Человек должен отвечать, или вы хотите, грубо говоря, чтоб какой-то ИИ *понимал вопросы* и давал осмысленные ответы?

Comment: То что нужно отвечать на запросы я знаю, и оно каждый раз разное. Нужно просто узнать как сделать так чтобы программа увидила ответы. Засунуть их ей в stdin или что-такое

Comment: А вы как программу запускаете ? по хорошему вы должны создать pipe для общения с программой, форкнуться, в потомке с помощью dup2 связать FD пайпа, предназначенный для чтения с дексриптором 0 (stdin), запустить программу через exec. после этого в родителе можете писать в свою сторону pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите, но чтобы перенаправить вывод одной программы на ввод другой, достаточно сделать pipe:

```
program1 | program2
```

Другой способ: генерируем вопрос программой (`question="$(program1)"`), делаем [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_(Unix)) из скрипта (`read answer`), полученный ответ перенаправляем на проверку другой программе (`program2 question answer`).